Where in a relational Algebra query do I perfrom the rename operation for attributes?
I am currently working through a few practice problems and realized I do not really know where in a Relational Algebra query I would perform the rename operation especially for attributes.
Should I put in front of everything like this:
$$\rho_{Attr1\,\leftarrow\,Attr2}(Table)\,\pi_{Attr2}(\,...\,)$$
or can I put it directly inside a projection / selection subscript within the query:
$$\pi_{\rho_{Attr1\,\leftarrow\,Attr2}(Table)\,}(\,...\,)$$
and if I have several Attributes I want to rename, how would properly incorporate them. Can I just write them down one after another like this:
$$\rho_{Attr1\,\leftarrow\,Attr2}(Table)\,,\, \rho_{Attr1\,\leftarrow\,Attr2}(Table)\,\,,\,...\,\pi_{Attr2}(\,...\,)$$
